# Does specman support checking severity reduction today?

Tags: specman

I am currently developing my own e-UVC and completed implementing checking monitor. Overall my environment is not mature and while running my tests, I would like to silence my checkers since I expect the failures yet would like to run the tests any 
a. Does specman support checking severity reduction today?  how can I do it?
b. Can I reduce severity of checks for specific instances?

Answer (score 0):

You can control this using set check command. From 14. 1 you can even specify a hierarchical path to specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

The ability of controlling checks per instance will be available in the 14.2 release
For now only per type is supported

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. 
Up ahead from version 14.1 you can silence checkers from specific path/topology. Each unit has its path and through test you can disable the checkers under it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using unit testing you can instantiate checker, and connect mockup to bypass the need to connect the checker to your VE.

Answer (score 0):

Specman supports check control for types of objects. Meaning that all instances can be changed. 
Starting in 14.2, you can control each instance separately, using heirarically name: you can turn on and off the checker using batch or gui command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_check(...)` to disable checks based on the error message:

```
extend sys {
    setup() is also {
        set_check("<match_string>", <new_severity>);
    };
};
```

`<match_string>` can be any regular expression and `<new_severity>` can be IGNORE, WARNING, ERROR_CONTINUE, ... Have a look at section 10.1.4 in the Specman Language Reference.

You can also disable specific checks in a specific struct/unit based on their name:

```
extend sys {
    setup() is also {
        set_check_by_name("<struct_type>", "<check_name>", <new_severity>);
    };
};
```

`<struct_type>` is the type of the struct (including subtype) and `<check_name>` is the name of the check (defined like `check <check_name> that ...`). Again, have a look at section 10.1.5

`set_check(...) and set_check_by_name(...)` are actions you can call from your *e* code. There is also the *set check* command you can call from the command line that emulates these.

This info is valid for Specman 13.20. Apparently in newer versions it will be possible to disable checks on specific instances.